# How would you write a Clojure SSH client?

Tags: clojure, ssh

How would you write a Clojure program that lets you securely send data or commands back and forth between your computer, and another computer on which you have a shell account? In Ruby, the program would be written using `Net::SSH`. How would this be done in Clojure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used this before - https://github.com/hugoduncan/clj-ssh

Easiest way to get the code is to use Leinengen or Cake.  Add [clj-ssh "0.2.0"] to your dependencies, and you should be good to go.